# How do I obtain the result of this testcase in this code challenge?

Tags: java, math

I am having troubles understanding a testcase of  this challege. The [problem](https://www.learneroo.com/modules/66/nodes/422) description is:

*A 2-sum is the sum of a list of numbers, but every number that's next to a 2 is counted twice. Given a list of numbers, print out their 2-sum.
For example, when given 1 2 3 4 as input, print 14, the sum of the numbers with 1 and 3 counted twice.*

Testcases:

1 2 3 4  = 14

2 1 3 6 2 6 = 33

7 9 -10 5 -5 3 -1 = 8

**2 2 8 2 2 14 2 2 = 68**

-23 13 7 6 9 11 -5 2 0 = 15

The testcase I do not understand is **2 2 8 2 2 14 2 2 = 68** there are 8 numbers, and I tried in this way:

2 + 14 + 4 + 28  + 4 = 58, and then I do know where are the other 10, It is confusing to me because there are 2 at the beginning, in the middle and at the end.
help appreciated

Comment: There is a sample solution for this problem here: http://www.programcreek.com/2012/12/leetcode-solution-of-two-sum-in-java/

Comment: @AndersonGreen thanks for answering but this is a different problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the question:

```
every number that's next to a 2 is counted twice
```

In other words, whenever there is a 2 directly *before* or *after* a number in the list, such number contributes twice to the total sum. In the test case you care about, all the numbers in the list is adjacent to a 2, so every number is counted twice, so the answer is:

```
2 * (2 + 2 + 8 + 2 + 2 + 14 + 2 + 2) = 2 * 34 = 68
```